# PI NoIR camera very bright picture outside

Tags: picamera

I'm trying to use the PiNOIR camera, in the 4th floor of a building, I'm trying to film outside I see black image, or white very bright image.

How would I resolve that issue ?

Comment: I think you should try tweaking the white balance of the camera.

Comment: What time of day do you get the black or the white image?

Comment: Please update your post with what commands you are using to take the images. Do you know how to adjust the exposure?